# How to bind HTML select element using either entity framework or MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

My current project is MVC based. I am stuck at trying to populate a select element from my SQL Server database table. Controller is receiving database data in a `DataTable` object. This data needs to be bound to a HTML select element at page load.

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Controller code GET method action

```
 // GET: SearchPopulate
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult SearchHome()
 {
        SearchPopulateMaster empPopulate = new SearchPopulateMaster();
        empPopulate.emp = PopulateEmps();
        return View();
 }

 private static List<SelectListItem> PopulateEmps() 
 {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        DataTable localdt = new DataTable();
        localdt = DALAcess.getDataFromSql("SELECT id,AgentName from [atmcolle_COMM_U88].[dbo].ATM_M_empMaster");
        return items;
 }
```

View code .cshtml file

```
<form asp-controller="SearchHome" asp-action="SearchHome">
    <!--Non-hardcoded retrieved from database-->
    <select name="selEmp" id="selEmp">
        <option>Please select one</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" />
    <!--Non-hardcoded retrieved from database-->
</form>
```

Comment: Would you kindly share your code snippet so that it can be reproducible?

Comment: Could you please have a look on the updated answer.

Comment: Cast erroer at this line
Line 24:             ViewBag.SearchPopulateMaster = new SelectList((IEnumerable)empPopulate, "Id", "AgentName")

Comment: Try to convert your `dataTable` into the list correctly.  You can [have a look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset) By the way are you using entity framework?

Comment: Why don't you directly get your List using `entityframework` or `Ado.net` , I don't think `datatable` is required here. You can use your dbContext class directly to get the agent list

Comment: Not sure of using entity framework. I started working on this particular MVC project just 3 days back. I am familiarizing myself with already developed code. now working page. but select element (dropdown) populated or not is getting hidden. something to work in css class or page-layout it seems. anyway thanks for quick answers. I will mark answer  once i can complete the task.

Comment: No problem , take your time, what does `DALAcess.getDataFromSql`? how you accessing database or how the query is executing? so that I can help you exactly.

Comment: DAL is a class may be Data Access Layer. and getDataFromSql a method that return ExecuteNonQuery() method. query executing simply by SQLClient objects. hope this clarify your question.

Comment: I guess DAL class use Ado.net concept. as Datatable is an object of ado.net

Comment: I have updated the answer with `Ado.net` example you can try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are trying to bind your `Data` into `HTML dropdown (HTML Select Tag)` which is coming  using `entity framework` from your database.

You can try below steps:

***`Model:`***

Lets say I have model like this:

```
public class Agent
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AgentName { get; set; }
    }
```

***`Controller:`***

```
    public ActionResult BindHtmlSelectElement()
    {
        //Bind Dropdown
        List<Agent> agent = PopulateEmps();
        ViewBag.Agent = new SelectList(agent, "Id", "AgentName");
        return View();
    }
```

***`View:`***

```
   @model MVCApps.Models.Agent
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "BindHtmlSelectElement";
    }
    
    <h4><strong>BindHtmlSelectElement</strong> </h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label  class="control-label col-md-2">Agent</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-items="ViewBag.Agent" value=""  class="form-control" asp-for="Id"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

***`Output:`***

[image]

> ***Note:***  In your `PopulateEmps` method return your agent list. And be conscious about the convension as well I made the id as `Id` be carefull while replace that to get rid of any error.

***`Update:`***
You can also try access your `Agent` query like below

```
public List<Agent> QueryBuilder()
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Server=ServerName;Database=YouDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"))
            {

                List<Agent> viewModeList = new List<Agent>();
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "SELECT id,AgentName from [atmcolle_COMM_U88].[dbo].ATM_M_empMaster";
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Agent viewModel = new Agent();
                    viewModel.Id= reader["id"].ToString(); // Remember to convert property in correct format
                    viewModel.AgentName = reader["AgentName"].ToString();
                    viewModeList.Add(viewModel);

                }
                reader.Close();
                command.Dispose();
                connection.Close();
                return viewModeList;
            }

        }
```

***`Update The Controller Like Below:`***

```
public ActionResult BindHtmlSelectElement()
    {
        //Bind Dropdown
        List<Agent> agent = QueryBuilder();
        ViewBag.Agent = new SelectList(agent, "Id", "AgentName");
        return View();
    }
```

Hope above steps guide you accordingly to achieve your goal.

Comment: List<StudentType> studentType = _context.studentTypes.ToList();
what is _context here?

Comment: Oh actually I have started working on it before your code so that the `_context` is my `entityframeowrk db connect` wait a bit, I am updating as per your scenario.